# How to get future publish/archive date for knowledge articles using apex?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Currently publishing articles in a custom VF page using the Knowledge Management Publishing Service Class, and publishing/archiving articles into the future.  But I can't seem to find a way to display this future date to the user.  It isn't stored it seems in any fields on the the article itself or in any apex jobs.

Does anyone know how SF displays this field on their own page?  And if they allow access to this date somehow via apex?

Comment: Any solution found for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the information you're looking for can be found in KnowledgeArticleVersion, probably under FirstPublishedDate.  So you'll want to query for the latest row in KnowledgeArticleVersion for the article in question and then pull its FirstPublishedDate to get the date you're looking for.